# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAccessToken')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
require('react-native')
import React from 'react'
import { create,act } from 'react-test-renderer'
import Login from '../src/components/pages/auth/LoginPage'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import App from '../App'
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps'
import { setAccessToken } from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";


test('snapshot',()=>{
    rootTree = renderer.create(<Login/>).toJSON()
    //  expect(rootTree).toMatchSnapshot();
})



jest.mock('@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps', () => ({
   
      setAccessToken: jest.fn(),
    
  }));
  
  describe('test', () => {
    it('should set access token', () => {
      // Call the function that sets the access token
      MapboxGL.default.setAccessToken('pk.eyJ1Ijoia21234Jja3U3dngzcmU1ajJjMndwaWZpcnRsc099yIn0.tVk9sh1nGAhc987668X3Q');
  
      // Check that the function was called with the correct access token
      expect(MapboxGL.default.setAccessToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith('pk.eyJ1Ijoia21234Jja3U3dngzcmU1ajJjMndwaWZpcnRsc099yIn0.tVk9sh1nGAhc987668X3Q');
    });
  });



● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAccessToken')

      34 | // import Geolocation from "react-native-geolocation-service";
      35 |
    > 36 | MapboxGL.setAccessToken(
         |          ^
      37 |   "pk.eyJ1Ijoia21234Jja3U3dngzcmU1ajJjMndwaWZpcnRsc099yIn0.tVk9sh1nGAhc987668X3Q"
      38 | );
      39 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/pages/main/map/map.js:36:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/pages/main/tab.js:4:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.184 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Getting issue while running test case using Jest

i tried various solution from chatGPT but nothing worked

question : do we need to provide valid access key while mocking?
right now i'm providing valid key in mocking.  for this question i changed some text in access key.

Help will be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is not that your key is valid or not, but that `MapboxGL` does not expose the `.setAccessToken` function, hence the `undefined`.

You should try log or check if MapboxGL is imported/defined